# MongoDB Error: Could not find path in schema

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I have method `setFirstNotDoneWordDefinitionToDone` it get parameters `id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId` and `modelDefinition: string`.

`testerRecord.words[0].definitions[0].definition` is an array and if it contains modelDefinition then `testerRecord.words[0].definitions[0].done` must be set to true.

```
async setFirstNotDoneWordDefinitionToDone(id: TId, modelDefinition: string) {
        await this.db.models.tester.updateOne(
            {
                _id: id,
            },
            {
                $set: {
                    "words.$[word].definitions.$[definition].done": true,
                },
            },
            {
                arrayFilters: [
                    { "word.done": false },
                    { "definition.definition": modelDefinition },
                ],
            }
        );
    }
```

But it throws an error **"Error: Could not find path "words.0.definitions.0.definition" in schema"**. However, it works fine by the moment when i start using second filter. For example:
`$set: { words.$[word].definitions: {} }` works right.

Spent a lot of time on this but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Mongoose version: `"mongoose": "7.1.1"`

**TesterDto:**

```
export class TestWordDefinitionDto {
    @Prop()
    definition: string[];
    @Prop()
    done: boolean;
}

export class TestWordDto {
    @Prop()
    term: string;
    @Prop([TestWordDefinitionDto])
    definitions: TestWordDefinitionDto[];
    @Prop()
    done: boolean;
}

export class TesterForCreateDto {
    @Prop({
        required: true,
        type: MongooseSchema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: UserDto.name,
    })
    userId: TId;
    @Prop([TestWordDto])
    words: TestWordDto[];
}

@Schema({
    collection: "testers",
    timestamps: { createdAt: true, updatedAt: false },
})
export class TesterDto extends TesterForCreateDto {
    _id: TId;
}
```

Schema is created just from TesterDto.

**Document from db:**
[image]

Will be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found mistake. A problem was in Schema. I cannot define nested object in way `@Prop([TestWordDto])`, I should create another schema for TestWordDto and put it in Prop.

Fixed:

```
@Schema({ _id: false })
export class TestWordDefinitionDto {
    @Prop()
    definition: string[];
    @Prop()
    done: boolean;
}
const TestWordDefinitionSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(
    TestWordDefinitionDto
);

@Schema({ _id: false })
export class TestWordDto {
    @Prop()
    term: string;
    @Prop([TestWordDefinitionSchema])
    definitions: TestWordDefinitionDto[];
    @Prop()
    done: boolean;
}
const TestWordSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(TestWordDto);

export class TesterForCreateDto {
    @Prop({
        required: true,
        type: MongooseSchema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: UserDto.name,
    })
    userId: TId;
    @Prop({ type: [TestWordSchema], default: [] })
    words: TestWordDto[];
}

@Schema({
    collection: "testers",
    timestamps: { createdAt: true, updatedAt: false },
})
export class TesterDto extends TesterForCreateDto {
    _id: TId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same problem when having nested schema.
This is how I fixed it and I hope it help someone out
there facing similar issue.

```
//Schema
{   ...,
    Activities: [
        {
            month: { type: String },
                days: [
                    {
                        day: { type: Number },
                        isChecked: { type: Boolean },
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    }
    
//Update
await Habit.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id},
    {
        achieved: totalAchieved,
        $set: {
            'activities.$[monthElement].days.$[dayElement].isChecked':
                isChecked,
        },
    },
    {
        arrayFilters: [
            {
                'monthElement.month': { $eq: month }
            },
            {
                'dayElement.day': { $eq: day },
            },
        ],
        new: true,
    }
);
```